# Azure Logic App: Why is For-Each-Loop for iterationg over XML is not entered?

Tags: xml, azure, foreach, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic app and want to access a blob storage via the http-connector.
(I know that there are dedicated blob-connectors but I can't use them).

The result of my http call to get a list of files looks like this:

```
{
    "body": {
        "$content": "77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz48.............",
        "$content-type": "application/xml"
    },
    "headers": {
        "Content-Length": "2198313",
        "Content-Type": "application/xml",
        "Date": "Wed, 11 Oct 2023 14:50:46 GMT",
        "Server": "Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "x-ms-client-request-id": "XXXXXXXX-ca8b-4876-8369-eff99d9fe0c3",
        "x-ms-request-id": "XXXXXXX-801e-005d-2d52-fc4b85000000",
        "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08"
    },
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

Inside the content field is a base64 encoded XML file which looks like this.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint=\"https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/\" ContainerName=\"landing\">
    <Blobs>
        <Blob>
            <Name>log.txt</Name>
            <Properties>
                <Creation-Time>Wed, 10 Aug 2022 11:13:23 GMT</Creation-Time>
                <Last-Modified>Wed, 10 Aug 2022 11:13:23 GMT</Last-Modified>
                <Etag>0x8DA7AC15724FC84</Etag>
                <Content-Length>0</Content-Length>
                <Content-Type>application/octet-stream</Content-Type>
                <Content-Encoding/>
                <Content-Language/>
                <Content-CRC64>AAAAAAAAAAA=</Content-CRC64>
                <Content-MD5/>
                <Cache-Control/>
                <Content-Disposition/>
                <BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
                <AccessTier>Hot</AccessTier>
                <AccessTierInferred>true</AccessTierInferred>
                <LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
                <LeaseState>available</LeaseState>
                <ServerEncrypted>true</ServerEncrypted>
            </Properties>
            <OrMetadata/>
        </Blob>
        <Blob>
            <Name>test.txt</Name>
            <Properties>
                <Creation-Time>Fri, 08 Sep 2023 09:26:20 GMT</Creation-Time>
                <Last-Modified>Fri, 08 Sep 2023 09:26:20 GMT</Last-Modified>
                <Etag>0x8DBB04DA9A2ED71</Etag>
                <Content-Length>0</Content-Length>
                <Content-Type>application/octet-stream</Content-Type>
                <Content-Encoding/>
                <Content-Language/>
                <Content-CRC64>AAAAAAAAAAA=</Content-CRC64>
                <Content-MD5/>
                <Cache-Control/>
                <Content-Disposition/>
                <BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
                <AccessTier>Hot</AccessTier>
                <AccessTierInferred>true</AccessTierInferred>
                <LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
                <LeaseState>available</LeaseState>
                <ServerEncrypted>true</ServerEncrypted>
            </Properties>
            <OrMetadata/>
        </Blob>
        ....
        ...
        ..
        .
        </Blobs>
        </EnumerationResults>
```

Now I want to iterate over every blob to gather the name and Last-Modified.
Therefore I set up two nested for-each loops with an xpath expression.

If I take a look at the run history of my workflow the result is failed and it seems that my for-each loop is never entered.

[image]

My first for-each expression looks like this:

```
xpath(xml(variables('Body')),'EnumerationResults/Blobs')
```

The second one:

```
xpath(xml(items('For_each')),'Blobs/Blob')
```

What could be the reason, why my loops are not working?

Comment: Can’t say for sure but change your Xpath expression to `//Blob` and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get the blob name and Last-Modified date in the following way-

***Workflow**-*

[image]

***Code**-*

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "For_each_1": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Set_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Name",
                                    "value": "@{xpath(xml(items('For_each_1')),'Blob/Name/text()')[0]}"
                                },
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            },
                            "Set_variable_1": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Last-Modified",
                                    "value": "@{xpath(xml(items('For_each_1')),'Blob/Properties/Last-Modified/text()')[0]}"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Set_variable": [
                                        "SUCCEEDED"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@xpath(xml(items('For_each')),'Blobs/Blob')",
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@xpath(xml(triggerbody()),'EnumerationResults/Blobs')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Last-Modified": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Last-Modified": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                        "name": "Last-Modified",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Name": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Name": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                        "name": "Name",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": { },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": { },
        "triggers": {
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://afreenstorage12.blob.core.windows.net/demo?restype=container&comp=list&sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=yyyyy&se=2023-10-26T20:08:12Z&st=2023-10-26T12:08:12Z&spr=https&sig=***********"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Http"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

***First For_each loop***-

**`xpath(xml(triggerbody()),'EnumerationResults/Blobs')`**

[image]

***Second For_each loop***-

**`xpath(xml(items('For_each')),'Blobs/Blob')`**

[image]

***Output***-

[image]

You can follow my approach to get the blob name and Last-Modified date.

Comment: Thx, what is inside the result of you HTTP step. Is the content base64 or plain XML?

Comment: @LStrike Http Output look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/yP5A0tM.png)

Comment: I get it to work with your description. Thanks a lot.